# Is it possible to make auto url mapping in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Is it possible to make auto url mapping in Spring MVC? For example, url `http://localhost/eshop/products` invokes ProductsController in eshop module without explicit @RequestMapping. System should know that the first param is a module and the second param is a controller. I don't want to do any changes in web.xml or in @RequestMapping each time I create a new controller.

Comment: You can do it by mapping in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this link 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s10.html

Convention over configuration with Spring MVC